# smart/automated/suggestive data mapping

Tags: machine-learning, integration, semantic-web, heuristics

I want to implement a tool which can transform (or at least suggest) one data model into another data model . For example one data model has two fields, 'first_name' and 'last_name' and 2nd data model has one field 'name' . Then tool should be able to suggest concatenation of 'first_name' and 'last_name'. A different use can be a mapping suggestion between two fields whose name are different but they mean the same thing .For ex map 'supplier_id' from source  data model to 'customer_id' in destination data model (A typical case of supplier relation management scenario).
I have seen approaches based on Machine Learning , heuristics and some research papers for semantic translation/mapping as well but couldn't find anything concrete .
Any pointers for start will be highly appreciated .